# Docker nginx and php-fpm

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I built some containers for our products(microservices based on php), and have a problem that I can't understand:

I have 3 containers:
- nginx
- php-fpm + code
- php-fpm + code

Nginx is configured as reverse-proxy for php-fpm's:

```
server {
listen 80;
#listen 443;

server_name 1.mydomain.com;

index index.php;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/sso-error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/sso-access.log;

root /1;

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Keep-Alive, User-Agent, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Content-Type';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'X-Domain-Token';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 86400;
    }
}

server {
listen 80;
#listen 443;

server_name 2.mydomain.com;

index index.php;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/ajax-broker.error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/ajax-broker.access.log;

root /2;

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm2:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Keep-Alive, User-Agent, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Content-Type';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'X-Domain-Token';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 86400;
  }
}
```

If, I mount volumes with code from both php-fpm to nginx container - all works,
however if I store code only in fpm container - nginx returns 404, also for *php URI's.

How can I setup nginx right without mounting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after few experiments i found solution, you should add one more **location** and comment **try_files** in php section:

```
server {
listen 80;
#listen 443;

server_name 1.mydomain.com;

index index.php;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/sso-error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/sso-access.log;

root /1;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.php;
}

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    #try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Keep-Alive, User-Agent, 
    X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Content-Type';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'X-Domain-Token';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 86400;
    }
}

server {
listen 80;
#listen 443;

server_name 2.mydomain.com;

index index.php;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/ajax-broker.error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/ajax-broker.access.log;

root /2;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.php;
}

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    #try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm2:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Keep-Alive, User-Agent, 
    X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Content-Type';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'X-Domain-Token';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 86400;
  }
}
```